# Casting SQL returns

Tags: c#, sql, casting

I am attempting to cast things I get back from a SQL query but I get an  error.

```
SqlCommand myCommand = "Select * from DB", xavierConnection);
SqlDataReader reader = null;
reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    _accountNumber = (int)reader["Account Number"];
    _callReportCode = (string)reader["Call Report Code"];
    _GLbalance = (double)reader["Bank Owned Principal Assets"];
}
```

What should I change to make the cast successful?

Comment: *What* error? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list.

Comment: `I get an error` - drink!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
_accountNumber = (int)reader["Account Number"];
_callReportCode = (string)reader["Call Report Code"];
_GLbalance = (double)reader["Bank Owned Principal Assets"];
```

To:

```
_accountNumber = int.Parse(reader["AccountNumber"].ToString());
_callReportCode = reader["CallReportCode"].ToString());
_GLbalance = double.Parse(reader["BankOwnedPrincipalAssets"].ToString());
```

Be aware that if any of the values coming from the database are `null` they'll throw a runtime exception. I leave for you to handle ...

Answer (score 1):

What line does the cast fail?  If it fails on int or double, check that the database fields aren't nullable.  If they are, try casting to (int?) and (double?), respectively.